# using custom user model with django-allauth gives error Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: activityhistory, app, ....,

Tags: django, django-allauth

I was trying to integrate django-allauth, and I tried to use custom user model. As stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), I created my model

```
class Client(AbstractBaseUser):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state_choices = (
        (0, 'Pending'),
        (1, 'Active'),
        (2, 'Deleted'),
        (3, 'Banned'),
    )
    state = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=state_choices, default=1, editable=False)
    objects = ClientManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname', 'lname']
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #########
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.fname

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.fname, self.lname)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        ###########

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        ###########

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        ###########
```

And the manager

```
class ClientManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, fname, lname, email, created_at, state):
        user = self.model(fname=fname, lname=lname, email=email, created_at=created_at, state=state)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, fname, lname, email, created_at, state):
        user = self.create_user(fname=fname, lname=lname, email=email, created_at=created_at, state=state)
        user.is_team_player = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Now, for the `admin.py` I did

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #A form for creating new users
    class Meta:
        model = models.Client
        fields = ('fname', 'lname', 'email')


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #A form for updating users
    class Meta:
        model = models.Client
        fields = ['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'is_admin']

class ClientAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)

    fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', )}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('fname', 'lname')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )  

    add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'fname', 'lname')}
    ),
)

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()




admin.site.unregister(models.Client)
admin.site.register(models.Client, ClientAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

In the `settings.py` I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.Client'`

Now when I go to `/admin` it gives me the error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin
Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: activityhistory, app, created_at, email, emailaddress, fname, id, is_active, is_admin, last_login, lname, logentry, password, socialaccount, state, testdevice
```

The stack trace tells me that since it treats `email` as username, and I use `username` and `password` for logging in, it gives me this error. Can't I make django ignore this restriction for admin only, or can I change the login mechanism for admin to use email rather than username?

I am trying to use `django-allauth` for letting a user sign-in through google or signup using his email and password. But its been a tough ride for me till now. If anybody has done that before or knows how to do it easily, pointing me to references would be great.

Answer (score 2):

First, add this to your custom user model:

```
class Client(AbstractBaseUser):
   class Meta:
      swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

Also, add this to your settings.py file:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
```

From the docs:

> (...) if your custom user model does not have a username field (again,
>   not to be mistaken with an e-mail address or user id), you will need
>   to set ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD to None. This will disable
>   username related functionality in allauth.

That worked for me.

References:

[1] https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth#custom-user-models

[2] https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ContribAuthImprovements